# Thumbs up/Down Mysql Query

Tags: mysql, select

I've two tables.

```
my_comment_thumbs [thumb_member_id, Cmt_id, thumb]
my_Comment [id, page, member_id, comment, ip]
```

For thumbs up, `thumb='1'`, and for thumbs down, `thumb='0'`.

[Not sure if that is very clear.]

I've been trying to get the thumbs up and thumbs down count for each comment.

What I've got so far [without a full understanding of what I have...]

```
SELECT 
SUM(IF(thumb='1', 1, 0)) AS t_up, 
SUM(IF(thumb='0', 1, 0)) AS t_down, 
id, member_id, comment, ip 
FROM my_Comment LEFT OUTER JOIN my_comment_thumbs ON member_id=thumb_member_id 
WHERE page='333'
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I don't have a data setup I could test this out on, I think this will work - but it isn't tested:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT count(thumb) FROM my_comment_thumbs WHERE thumb=1) as t_up, 
    (SELECT count(thumb) FROM my_comment_thumbs WHERE thumb=0) as t_down, 
    id, member_id, comment, ip 
FROM my_Comment 
LEFT OUTER JOIN my_comment_thumbs ON member_id=thumb_member_id 
WHERE page='333'
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: The join wasn't necessary. Otherwise you got me in the right direction.. Thank so you much!

Answer (score 0):

for thumb=1 or thumb =0 ;

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_comment_thumbs,my_Comment 
   WHERE   
       my_Comment.id=my_comment_thumbs.Cmt_id 
          AND 
       my_comment_thumbs.thumb=1 
          AND 
       member_id=thumb_member_id;"
```

Comment: Thank you, perdickss. I'm trying to get the thumb count [up and down] plus the comment data.

Comment: SELECT (SELECT count(*) FROM my_comment_thumbs WHERE thumb=1) as t_up, (SELECT count(*) FROM my_comment_thumbs WHERE thumb=0) as t_down , id , member_id , `comment`, `ip` FROM my_comment , my_comment_thumbs WHERE my_Comment.id=my_comment_thumbs.Cmt_id AND   my_comment_thumbs.thumb=1  AND member_id=thumb_member_id AND page='333';